# Connect points based on same value in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Given this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foobar'], 'x': [3, 4, 1, 5, 5.5, 5.2, 8]})
```

How can I draw a line plot connecting the data points that have the same 'a', e.g. connect points 3 and 4 because 'foo' is the same, whereas the last data point, 8 is plotted as just a dot, by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
df.reset_index().pivot_table(index=  'index', columns= 'a', values = 'x').plot(marker = '*')
```

Alternative via `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x = 'index', y = 'x' , hue = 'a', data = df.reset_index(), marker = '*')
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How can I use just one color for the line?

Comment: One way to do it is to get the unique values of the 'a' column and create a palette where you're assigning the chosen color to each value, then pass it to the palette argument of sns.lineplot().